# Strobe light for android

Tags: android, timer, runnable

I've searched on stackoverflow and used the algo that uses Handler and postDelayed messages to turn on and turn off the light.

The algo runs perfectly.... here is what I did:

```
if(mActive)//control the runnable thread
    {
        if(mSwap)//toggler for strobe
        {
            //Turn Flash On
            cam = Camera.open();
            Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            cam.setParameters(p);
            cam.startPreview();
            mSwap = false;
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            //Turn Flash Off

            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
            mSwap = true;
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1);


        }
    }
```

but I cannot increase the switching to match the strobe frequency of those apps that are on the market...

Is there any other logic that I can use(instead of queuing the messages )?? 
Will using a timer give better result?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try a timer? Also, why use the camera preview? And all the open and closing seems a bit too much as well. Hell, you are even allocating a new `Camera` object all the time.

Comment: yes I suspected that...the reallocation might be taking time...can I use something else other that camera preview?? I had problems when only allocating the camera once... it could not execute cam.release after cam = Camera.open...my cam is global

Comment: Perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163012/how-to-use-the-camera-flash-light-as-torch can help you.

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly...I used separate global parameters for turning on and turning of... Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are allocating and deallocating the `Camera` object each time you switch on/off your torch. This takes quite some time every time.

To fix, move the allocation / deallocation to the `onStart` and `onStop` methods and only do the bare minimum to switch the light on and off.